# HTTParty Google maps directions between origin and destination.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My goal: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=montreal&destination=toronto&sensor=false

My class:

```
class GoogleMap
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://maps.googleapis.com'

  attr_accessor :origin, :destination

   def initialize(service, page)
    @options = { query: {origin: origin, destination: destination} }
  end

  def directions
    self.class.get("/maps/api/directions/json", @options)
  end
end
```

Currently when I run this on the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> g = GoogleMap.new("montreal", "toronto")
=> #<GoogleMap:0x007fcaeeb88538 @options={:query=>{:origin=>nil, :destination=>nil}}>
irb(main):002:0> g.directions
=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fcaeeb60b00 parsed_response={"error_message"=>"Invalid request. Missing the 'origin' parameter.", "routes"=>[]...
```

Problem is: `{:query=>{:origin=>nil, :destination=>nil}}` origin and destination are nil.

I would like to know how I would achieve:

```
irb(main):001:0> g = GoogleMap.new("montreal", "toronto")
=> #<GoogleMap:0x007fcaeeb88538 @options={:query=>{:origin=>montreal, :destination=>toronto}}
```

And then when I run:

`g.directions` I get output of http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=montreal&destination=toronto&sensor=false

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to change your

`def initialize(service, page)`

to

`def initialize(origin, destination)`

Or you can do `g.origin = "montreal"` and `g.destination = "toronto"` before you call `g.directions`